# Number based Marker SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I currently have a table function which will be used to remove duplicate employer entries and update the end date.

Currently my table is as follows

```
Memberid    startdate    enddate    Employerid
10220      1978-08-07   2007-12-31     1153
10220      2008-01-01   2011-06-16     1811
10220      2011-06-17   2011-06-30     1124
10220      2011-07-01   2011-07-18     1124
10220      2011-07-19   2011-07-31     1178
10220      2011-08-01   2011-08-17     1178
10220      2011-08-18   2011-09-18     1124
10220      2011-09-19   2011-10-18     1124
10220      2011-10-19   2011-11-16     1124
10220      2011-11-17   2011-12-12     1124
10220      2011-12-13   2012-01-18     1124
10220      2012-01-19   2012-02-16     1124
10220      2012-02-17   2012-03-18     1124
10220      2012-03-19   2012-04-18     1124
10220      2012-04-19      NULL        1124
```

I would like to put in a counter through a table-valued function so that it counts every time there is an employer change

e.g.

```
Memberid    startdate    enddate    Employerid    Count
10220      1978-08-07   2007-12-31     1153        1
10220      2008-01-01   2011-06-16     1811        2
10220      2011-06-17   2011-06-30     1124        3
10220      2011-07-01   2011-07-18     1124        3
10220      2011-07-19   2011-07-31     1178        4
10220      2011-08-01   2011-08-17     1178        4
10220      2011-08-18   2011-09-18     1124        5
10220      2011-09-19   2011-10-18     1124        5
10220      2011-10-19   2011-11-16     1124        5
10220      2011-11-17   2011-12-12     1124        5
10220      2011-12-13   2012-01-18     1124        5
10220      2012-01-19   2012-02-16     1124        5
10220      2012-02-17   2012-03-18     1124        5
10220      2012-03-19   2012-04-18     1124        5
10220      2012-04-19      NULL        1124        5
```

Comment: What is your output ordered by? If you want to define a numbering schema - you need to have something to order the rows by ...

Comment: ordered by memberid and startdate asc